# button RUN in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I had a weird problem in Android Studio 2.0 preview, I clone a project from a local GitLab, everythings Ok, gradle build pereferctely, but when I click on RUN, nothing happend (no error, no message in log) it sounds like the button not working, I check the iml files everythings ok.
Hope someone help me.

[image]

Comment: in AS there is another log window called "run"...is here anything to see?

Comment: check the capture above, no information or message

Comment: there must be also a "run" tab near the "logcat" tab. Are you trying this on a emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Update of Android-studio resolve the problem.